# Pandas series string manipulation using Python - 1st two chars flip and append to end of string

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have a column (series) of values I'm trying to move characters around and I'm going nowhere fast! I found some snippets of code to get me where I am but need a "Closer".  I'm working with one column, datatype (STR). Each column strings are a series of numbers.  Some are duplicated. These duplicate numbers have a (n-) in front of the number. The (n) number will change based on how many duplicate numbers strings are listed. Some may have two duplicates, some eight duplicates. Doesn't matter, order should stay the same.

I need to go down through each cell or string, pluck the (n-) from the left of string, swap the two characters around, and append it to the end of the string. No number sorting needed. The column is 4-5k lines long and will look like the example given all the way down. No other special characters or letters. Also, the duplicate rows will always be together no matter where in the column.

My problem is the code below actually works and will step through each string, evaluate it for a dash, then process the numbers in the way I need. However, I have not learned how to get the changes back into my dataframe from a python for-loop. I was really hoping that somebody had a niffy lambda fix or a pandas apply function to address the whole column at once.  But I haven't found anything that I can tweak to work. I know there is a better way than slowly traversing down through a series and I would like to learn.

Two possible fixes needed:

1. Is there a way to have the code below replace the old df.string value with the newly created df.string value? If so, please let me know.
2. I've been trying to read up on df.apply using the split feature so I can address the whole column at once.  I understand it's the smarter play.  Is there a couple of lines code that would do what I need?

Please let me know what you think.  I appreciate the help. Thank you for taking the time.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("E:\Book2.xlsx")

df.column1=df.column1.astype(str)

for r in df['column1']:            #Finds Column
if bool(re.search('-', r))!=True:  #test if string has '-' 
    continue
else:
    a = []                         #string holder for '-'
    b = []                         #string holder for numbers
    for c in r:
        if c == '-':               #if '-' then hold in A
            a.append(c)
        else:
            b.append(c)            #if number then hold in B
    t = (''.join(b + a))           #puts '-' at the end of string
    z = t[1:] + t[:1]              #picks up 1st position char and moves to end of string
    r = z                          #assigns new created string to df.column1 value

print(df)

Starting File:         Ending File:

column1                column1
41887                  41887
1-41845                41845-1
2-41845                41845-2
40905                  40905
1-41323                41323-1
2-41323                41323-2
3-41323                41323-3
41778                  41778
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use df.str.replace():

If we recreate your example with a file containing all your values and retain column1 as the column name:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('file.txt')
df.columns=['column1']
df['column1']=df['column1'].str.replace('(^\d)-(\d+)',r'\2-\1')
print(df)
```

This will give the desired output. Replace the old column with new one, and do it all in one (without loops).

```
#in 
41887                 
1-41845               
2-41845                
40905               
1-41323               
2-41323                
3-41323               
41778  
#out 
    column1
0   41887
1   41845-1
2   41845-2
3   40905
4   41323-1
5   41323-2
6   41323-3
7   41778
```

Comment: Thank You Samman for helping me with this.  Now I just need to figure out your code piece so I can learn from it.  Thanks again.!

Comment: Well first line open the text file containing the numbers, 2nd line just inserts a column with the name column1. 3rd line searches all the values in column1 for a specific string format. The argument is ```str.replace(string to replace, string to replace it with)``` \d means any number, the + means more than one (i.e. \d would be 1, \d+ would be 10). ^ means the line starts with that. \2 and \1 are the positions of your string search (i.e. \1 is the value obtained from (^\d) and \2 is from (\d+). So in short, we are looking for any string that starts with a single digit, has a hyphen (-), and

Comment: is followed by multiple numbers (e.g.. 1-41845), replace this with the value from (^\d), which is 1, and and (\d+) which is 41845. When you order them \2-\1 it becomes 41845-1. Here is a start to understand some of the terminology https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: That's Awesome!!  So many little pieces and it works well together.  I appreciate the explanation and link.  Thank You.